# How to delete the specific div using the unique key in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, mern

When I click the delete button of a div, I want to remove that specific div from the container array without affecting the other divs. I have tried various approaches, but each time I click the delete button, all the divs become empty again.

```
 import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(1); 
  let id = 0; 
  
  const [container, setContainer] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => { 
    setItems(items + 1); 
    id = uuidv4();
  }
const handleDelete = (key) =>{ 
  console.log(key); 
  const updatedContainer = container.filter((i, index) => index !== key);
  setContainer(updatedContainer);
  setItems(items - 1);

}
  useEffect(() => {
    const newContainer = [];
   
        for(let i = 0 ; i< items ; i++){ 
         
         newContainer.push( <div key={id} className="subcontainer2">
          <div className="item1">
          <span>Item </span>
            <input type="text" placeholder='item name' className="subinputfields" />
          </div>
          <div className="item2">
          <span>Quantity</span>
          <input type="number" placeholder='1' className="qty" /></div>
          <div className="item2"><span>Price/Rate</span> 
           <input type="number" className='price' name="price" min="0.00" step="0.01" placeholder='&#8377; 0.00' />
          </div>
          <div className="item2"><span>Action</span>
           <img src="delete.png"  className='deletebtn' onClick = {() => handleDelete(id)} alt="" /></div>
        </div>); 
        }
       setContainer(newContainer);
      }, [items]);
```

> And here is the return jsx

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        { container }
       
        <div onClick = { handleClick} className="addbtn">
            Add Items
        </div>
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Please help anyone how to resolve this issue

Comment: You probably shouldn't use id libraries like `uuid` to add values to the keys as keys have to be consistent between renders.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using the same `id` for all the items in the container, which is why all the items are being deleted when you click the delete button.

Here is the updated `useEffect` :

```
useEffect(() => {
        const newContainer = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            const itemId = uuidv4();
            newContainer.push(
                <div key={itemId} className='subcontainer2'>
                    <div className='item1'>
                        <span>Item </span>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='item name' className='subinputfields' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='item2'>
                        <span>Quantity</span>
                        <input type='number' placeholder='1' className='qty' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='item2'>
                        <span>Price/Rate</span>
                        <input
                            type='number'
                            className='price'
                            name='price'
                            min='0.00'
                            step='0.01'
                            placeholder='&#8377; 0.00'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='item2'>
                        <span>Action</span>
                        <img src='delete.png' className='deletebtn' onClick={() => handleDelete(i)} alt='' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
        setContainer(newContainer);
    }, [items]);
```

But i'd recommend using `useRef`